# How Can a function act like a descriptor?

Tags: python, descriptor

```
def typed_property(name, expected_type):
    storage_name = '_' + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, storage_name)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
            raise TypeError('{} must be a {}'.format(name, expected_type))
        setattr(self, storage_name, value)
    return prop


class Person:
    name = typed_property('name', str)
    age = typed_property('age', int)
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Function typed_property() acts like a descriptor. Why prop() is called when executing this code line (name = typed_property('name', str))?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "descriptor".  `typed_property` allows a property to call a function for additional processing.  `prop()` is not called when executing the line you mentioned.  It is called when executing `self.name = name`.  The `@prop.setter` makes it so the object can respond to property calls like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `typed_property` to set the value of the class properties `name` and `age`, you are really defining those to be methods to use to access the instance values `self.name` and `self.age`. This is the same as below omitting age for simplicity:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        print("=== ACESSING")
        return self.name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        print("=== MUTATING")
        self.name = name
```

This marks the `name(self)` method as the accessor for `self.name`, and `name(self, val)` as the mutator. The mutator is called whenever you try to change (mutate) the value of its assigned property, in this case `self.name`. This includes when you are calling it in the `__init__` method. However, using the class as defined above will result in an infinite recursion because I am calling the mutator from inside the mutator. So "=== MUTATING" will be printed ending in a recursion error. So a small adjustment is needed:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        print("=== ACCESSING")
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        print("=== MUTATING")
        self._name = val
```

Now that underlying property is name `_name` rather than `name` the mutator will set the value of `_name` rather than setting it for `name` and recur into itself infinitely. For example, using the class as defined above:

```py
>>> p = Person("joshmeranda")
>>> p.name
=== ACCESSING
"joshmeranda"
```